# breaking out of sub after if statement in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am trying to write code that opens the saveFileDialog only if the variable 'file' **is not** empty and generates an error message if 'file' **is** empty. The following code will pop up a error message box when 'file' is empty but will proceed to open the saveFileDialog anyway.

```
Public Shared Sub DownloadFile(cloudId As CloudIdentity, directoryPath As String, file      As String)

Try
Dim cloudFilesProvider = New CloudFilesProvider(cloudId)

If file = "" Then
cloudFilesProvider.GetObjectSaveToFile("EstherTest", directoryPath, file)

End If
Catch

If file = "" Then
MessageBox.Show("Please select file to view")
End If
End Try
End Sub
```

Can you please direct me.

Comment: You'll want to learn how to step through your code. Doing so, you would have quickly realized the mistake that Serv pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong equality operator in your first if-statement.

In humand words, you are telling the compiler:

> If `file` is equal to "" then do ... (`If file = "" Then`)

What you are trying to say is: if `file` is NOT equal to "" (`If file <> "" Then`).

As a second note: Unless an exception occurs, your second if statement will never be called, because the catch block will never be reached. You should put the second clause in a `else` or `else if clause`.
I've removed the try catch block for simplicity (and because I'm not really good at the vb.net syntax).

All in all your code should look like this:

```
Public Shared Sub DownloadFile(cloudId As CloudIdentity, directoryPath As String, file      As String)
    Dim cloudFilesProvider = New CloudFilesProvider(cloudId)
    ' if file is not emtpy, proceed
    If file <> "" Then
        cloudFilesProvider.GetObjectSaveToFile("EstherTest", directoryPath, file)    
    ' else if file is empty, show message box
    else if file = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please select file to view")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I couldnt figure out why it worked before and then crashed :)

Comment: it still proceeds to open the save file dialog

Comment: You should step into your code and check the values of `file`. Logically this piece of code is correct.